# $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ entire, $|f(z)|\ge \frac{1}{1+|z|^n}$. Is there a counterexample?

Tags: complex-analysis

In lecture we had the following claim: Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ an entire function such that there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$: $|f(z)|\ge \frac{1}{1+|z|^n}$. Then $f$ is constant.

we proved this Claim by Liouville, but something is still unclear to me. My question: Why isn't $f(z)=e^z=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}$ a counterexample of this claim?

Comment: $|e^z| = e^x$ ($x$ real part of $z$) and $e^x \to 0 $ as $x\to -\infty$ so there exists no such fixed $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ has no zeros, and $g(z) = {1 \over f(z)}$ is entire and
satisfies $|g(z)| \le 1+|z|^n$, hence $g$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ or less (use Cauchy's estimate to see this). If $g$ is not constant, it has a zero $z_0$, which contradicts
$g(z)f(z) = 1$.

If $f(z) = e^z$, then for real $x >0$ the bound would give
$f(-x) = e^{-x} \ge {1 \over 1+x^n}$, or ${e^x \over 1+x^n} \le 1$, which
cannot hold for large $x$.